# Gradle, Groovy-all-2.3.6.jar Not found

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

While working in Apache Cordova tools for Visual Studio 2015 I came across following error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find JAR
>   'groovy-all-2.3.6.jar' required by module 'gradle-core' using
>   classpath or distribution directory
>   'C:\Users\Admin.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b\gradle-2.2.1'

**--From Output**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error BLD106  ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for
>   command: cmd with args:
>   /s,/c,"E:\Proj\BlankCordovaApp3\BlankCordovaApp3\BlankCordovaApp3\platforms\android\gradlew
>   cdvBuildDebug -b
>   E:\Proj\BlankCordovaApp3\BlankCordovaApp3\BlankCordovaApp3\platforms\android\build.gradle
>   -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true" BlankCordovaApp3        1

**--Actual Error**

Its working fine in Ripple, but when the build switched to Device the above error occurs

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or proxy server?

Comment: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from build errors in VS. I’m hoping to chat with folks like you who have encountered build errors and reached out to the community for troubleshooting. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. rsalva [at] Microsoft [dot] com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just copied "groovy-all-2.3.6.jar" to "C:\Users\Admin.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b\gradle-2.2.1/lib" and it worked.

It might have corrupted.

Thanks